# Python 3 IDLE - input("string"), IDLE close before i can read the error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

When i "Run" it in the editor "Pychar", it works perfectly, but not when i use the python IDLE. When i enter a "a" or any other string it just returns an error but i it closes immediately.

```
my_string = input("Insert string: ")
print(my_string)
```

And i have tried putting in a new input() at the bottom, to make it wait for a last input before closing, but it still shuts down.

So if one could tell me what i'm doing wrong or how i can make the IDLE stay 
open after the error message, that be great :D

The version of the IDLE is 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59)

Comment: Wild guess: Pychar is using 3.X, but IDLE is using 2.7. In 2.7, if the string you pass to `input` is not a valid python expression, it will crash with a SyntaxError. If IDLE says "2.7" when you try `import sys; print(sys.version)`, then use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: IDLE closes when stdin (standard input) is closed.  Are you entering something which might do this, like CTRL+D?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: To test Kevin's hypothesis, which I suspect is correct, start IDLE and enter `import sys; sys.version` at the `>>> ` prompt.

Comment: The version is 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) 
And i just type in a string like "a" or "Hello world", but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once it has an error, it will quit the program unless you catch it.

Try this:

```
try:
    my_string = input("Insert string: ")
    print(my_string)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    input()
```

Comment: That did not work, it still just shuts down instantly.
--- It is python 3.x so should "print e" not be "print(e)"?

Comment: It _should_ be `print(e)`.  I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Okay so it worked (forgot to delete the old line, ups...)
know it returns:
    "insert string: x"
    "name 'x' is not defined" 
Then when i click Enter again, it shows an error message for 1 sec and the closes.

Comment: That sounds like you are using Python 2.  If you are, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: Okay so the "raw_input()" works in the IDLE but not in the PyCharm editor (i'm working on a python 3.4 project). Could that be because Pychar is 3.4 and IDLE maybe is executing in 2.x instead of the 3.4 version which i have installed?

Comment: It works perfectly if i go over to working in python 2.4, so think that's what i'm going to do. Does that change a lot for a "newbee" like me?

Comment: Not really.  Most stuff that works in Python 3 works in Python 2.  For instance, in Python 3 you do `print(something)` rather than `print something` in Python 2, but even in Python 2 `print(something)` will work just as well.  If you are a "newbee", you will probably not be bothered by the name of the builtin module being different, or various other modules for that matter.  There are various slight differences like that, but they probably won't effect your program.  [Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) they talk about the differences between them.